# Sending HTML forms on email

Tags: javascript, html, mandrill

I am working on a polling website and i need to send a poll to users on email itself. Users should be able to vote on the poll from the email itself without leaving their page.

Right now I am using mandrill to send emails, but whenever i send a mail containing radio buttons; the buttons are not getting displayed in the mail and only text portion of the mail persists.

How can this be done?

Right now I am trying to send this simple html form by creating a template in mandrill

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Widget Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>
<body style="width:900px;margin:0 auto;">

<form method="post" action="https://www.<xyx>.com/servemailpollresponse/">
<p>Will you attend?<br />
<input type="radio" name="will_attend"> Sure!<br />
<input type="radio" name="will_attend">Maybe?<br />
<input type="radio" name="will_attend">Nope.<br />
<input type="submit"></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Complement your question, with your code.

Comment: _... only text portion of the mail persists._ could mean your mail is sent as text only.

Comment: @LGSon yes only plain text is getting sent

Comment: To make your form work it has to be sent as html.

Comment: @LGSon I didn't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: When sending mail one can send them as text or html, are you aware of that?

Comment: @LGSon No, I was not aware of that till now. Thanks for letting me know. I will try to send my mail as html

Comment: There is a "html" key in the request JSON that needs to be set, or you can create a template in Mandrill and pass in the text you need to add. [API docs here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html)

Comment: Let us know if that solved your issue, and as well choose an answer which best answer the question.

Comment: @LGSon there is field called html_content and i am sending my complete html code in this field only in that case it is working and i have tried every thing mentioned in the document but it is not working using the templates.

Comment: The main issue for this question was sending it as html to make form work, if you need the template to work, please add that as a new question. Please choose an answer, if any, that bests solve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... only text portion of the mail persists.

This could mean your mail is sent as text only.

When sending mail one can send them as text or html, and have a form work it has to be sent as html.

In Mandrill there is a "html" key in the request JSON that needs to be set, or you can create a template and pass in the text you need to add.

[Link to API docs here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html)

Note: And, as [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) wrote, radio buttons need value

Answer (score 0):

Add value to the radios. Right now there is nothing to send

Like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="will_attend" value="sure"> Sure!<br />
<input type="radio" name="will_attend" value="maybe">Maybe?<br />
<input type="radio" name="will_attend" value="nope">Nope.<br />
```

Comment: Then the issue is on the server. Please post the servermailpollresponse script too in your question